# Python - newly created virtualenv gives a list of global modules

Tags: python

I setup a virtualenv and went ahead and activated the virtualenv and when I did a pip freeze for some reason it gave me a list of all global modules installed. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what exactly it is that you're doing?

Comment: What is your operating system, and Python specs?

Comment: @nir0s I'm trying to localize my modules per projet. python 2.7 Mac OSX

Comment: I understand.. but it's hard to see what the problem is without some output. Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the folder name of the generated virtualenv folder, and this is what caused the issue, even when it was accessed to a correct directory path:

```
source edited_env_name/bin/activate
```

Comment: Which is why you post the output of what you do.

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is the behavior of `virtualenv`, it creates a new `python environment` with the current system`s`site-packages`.

To avoid that behavior you can use `--no-site-packages` flag, It removes the standard `site-packages` directory from sys.path`

Comment: Except [`--no-site-packages` is on by default](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption--no-site-packages).

Comment: and if you work with virtualenv you always see it the installed packages in that env.